# Unable to Cross CORS Policy - Angular with spring boot security

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

Unable to Cross CORS Policy when using angular as client and spring boot as my server. I have included spring security also.

```
    @EnableWebSecurity
            public class WebSecurityConfig  extends 
              WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("Dinesh").password("{noop}password").roles("USER");

}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.cors().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/spot/login").hasRole("USER").and().httpBasic();
}


@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","OPTIONS"));
      configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

}

My Angular Service:

```
      this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/spot/login", 
      {'userName':userName,'password':password}).subscribe(
  (responseData)=>{
    if(responseData == "Success") {
      sessionStorage.setItem('loggedUserName',userName);
      this.router.navigate(['/welcome']);
    }
    else { 
      this.router.navigate(['/invalid']);
    }
  }
);
```

Kindly suggest solution.

Received Error in browser console as :

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/spot/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Answer (score 1):

If you review the dev console network tab of the Angular application, you will that an `OPTIONS` request is made by the browser when the request is not a [simple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests), but rather a [preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests). You need to update the allowed methods of the Spring application to include `OPTIONS`. Try updating:

```
configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
```

To:

```
configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","OPTIONS"));
```

Also you will likely, depending on the headers sent from the Angular application, need to configure the allowed headers via `addAllowedHeader` or `setAllowedHeaders()`:

```
configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
// configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
```

Finally, you can remove the following header from your Angular HttpClient call as it has no positive impact on CORS from the client side:

```
{headers:new HttpHeaders({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080'})
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Hi.! Tried the above steps . Still the same error. Am I missing something

Comment: @DineshNarayan update your question with your most up to date code

Comment: Edited now.  Please check